# The prepositions "in/at/for" with a game

Tags: prepositions

Can we use any of the prepositions' in, at, for' in the following construction?

The ltalian team won the gold medal ....volleyball.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally heard all three used, but I believe "in" is most proper.  To give the extended version, you would write:

"The Italian team won the gold medal in the event of volleyball".

Perhaps this is why "in" tends to be more favored here.